# The "Confirm" parameter can't be used on the "Set-Mailbox"

Tags: powershell, try-catch, powershell-2.0, exchange-server

I am trying to Set mailbox permissions for a user using an administrator account.

try{

```
Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipleName -AuditEnabled $True -AuditLogAgeLimit 
"03.00:00:00" -AuditDelegate "SoftDelete", "HardDelete", "SendAs", "Create", 
"FolderBind" -Confirm:$false
```

}catch{

```
if($Error)
   {
     Write-Host "Error"
   }
```

}

I am not able to catch this error in the catch block($Error).

Error::
The "Confirm" parameter can't be used on the "Set-Mailbox" cmdlet because it isn't present in the role definition for the current user.

Check the management roles assigned to you, and try again.

Any lead will be appreciated. Cheers...

Comment: You don't need to say `if ($Error)` in the `catch` block. You already know there's an error because you're in `catch`.

Comment: as Bill mentioned, no need to use `if` in catch block here and for confirm, try with out mentioning `-Confirm` parameter and see whether it is asking for the confirmation or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add to add the `-ErrorAction Stop` to the `Set-Mailbox` cmdlet:

```
Set-Mailbox $UserPrincipleName -AuditEnabled $True -AuditLogAgeLimit 
"03.00:00:00" -AuditDelegate "SoftDelete", "HardDelete", "SendAs", "Create", 
"FolderBind" -ErrorAction Stop
```